# IMPORTRANGE, where range shifts often, to different spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

What I have: a client information spreadsheet that contains company information including their last order date following the status of their account (active/follow-up).

**What I need**: the last order date for each company to update on a different spreadsheet for a different team to view the information.

I have figured out how to import a range on one main spreadsheet to different spreadsheets that need this specific data. However, the main spreadsheet I am referring to, the column for the company often shifts which means that when we have inactive clients, we need to delete from the spreadsheet.

Example:

```
Company A (column AA) last ordered 5/5/2019 (used IMPORTRANGE: Link(SPREADSHEET!AA8)  
Company B (column Y) last order 6/15/2018
```

We need to move Company B to inactive so we delete Company B. When deleting Company B, Company A moves to column Z which is not the same formula in the other spreadsheet.

Is there a way I can "fixate" the certain cell range to correlate their last order date with the company name without having to go in and search each company for the column letters to put into the formula.

Comment: Welcome. Please add more details about the data layout. The best is to add a sample data (you could put fictitious data but should be representative).  What I would like to see if there is company ID o name that could be used to in a lookup.  Also add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén Each company is in a different column with all their information: date onboarded, address, phone number, commission structure, and pricing exceptions on the main client information spreadsheet. The 2 other spreadsheets I use for each type of client (mail-order) and another type of client (traditional). All I need is the cell that says last ordered date to update appropriately to the specific company, but data gets mixed as we move certain clients in the middle of the spreadsheet to inactive and delete them. I used a forum on Google to find the import range but tried to call google

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add to it all the relevant details.

Comment: support to help me with this, but they directed me to this forum. I didn't know how to ask this certain question in google without having to provide all the information in my first forum message. I don't know how to attach a sample data. Please advise

Comment: please post help requests about how to use this site on [meta] (those who not have enough reputation could ask on [meta.se]).